# How to i can change android navigation view item with underline color

Tags: android

This is my layout

[image]

expectation
i want display likely this

[image]

this is my main.xml with group and item

how to add item @+id/nav_open_account line top and bottom

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_1468839149_free_17"
        android:title="Investor Profile" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_house"
        android:title="Property Activity" />
</group>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:id="@+id/nav_open_account"
        android:title="New Investment" />
</group>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="Message" />
</group>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:background="@color/profileBackground"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: Please consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . We can't answer a question like that...

Comment: @a.g.thamays rather than putting your requirement, come back to SO with what you have done to expect a suggestion/solution

Comment: You need to group id as I am Give  In My Answer

Comment: ok thanks, and how to change that line color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Take Group For you want to underline below**

**LIKE THAT**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/FIRST"
        android:icon="@drawable/FIRST"
        android:title="FIRST" />
    </group>

   //tHIS sHOWING uNDERLINE bELOW
<group android:id="@+id/grp2"  android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/SECOND"
        android:icon="@drawable/SECOND"
        android:title="SECOND" />
    </group>
   //tHIS sHOWING uNDERLINE bELOW
<group android:id="@+id/THIRD"  android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/THIRD"
        android:icon="@drawable/THIRD"
        android:title="THIRD" />
    </group>
  //tHIS sHOWING uNDERLINE bELOW
<group android:id="@+id/grp4"  android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/FOUR"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_recommended"
        android:title="FOUR" />
    </group>
    //tHIS sHOWING uNDERLINE bELOW

    <item
        android:id="@+id/FIVE"
        android:icon="@drawable/FIVE"
        android:title="FIVE" />
     //tHIS IS nOT sHOWING uNDERLINE bELOW

    <item
        android:id="@+id/SIX"
        android:icon="@drawable/SIX"
        android:title="SIX" />

  //tHIS IS nOT sHOWING uNDERLINE bELOW
<group android:id="@+id/grp5"  android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/SEVEN"
        android:icon="@drawable/SEVEN"
        android:title="SEVEN" />
    </group>

  //tHIS sHOWING uNDERLINE bELOW
   </menu>
```

**Do this For Color of line**

> **in your xml set theme to navigationView**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:background="@color/profileBackground"
app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
android:theme="@style/NavigationView" />
```

**take in your style.xml**

```
   <style name="NavigationView" parent="ThemeToolbar.NavigationView" >
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/yourcolor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/yourcolor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @a.g.thamays Please check the updated answer for color of underlined...

Comment: @a.g.thamays have you problem yet.?

Answer (score 0):

If you will use menu NavigationView then not possible because they follow Material design guide line.

If you want to implement functionality like attached(above) image then you can use RecycleView or ListView or add some layout with NavigationView.